# How do I get my area filled beneath my d3 line chart to be a gradient?

Tags: css, d3.js, gradient, linechart, area

I'm using d3 v4.  I would like to create a line chart where the area beneath the graph is an area filled by a gradient going from dark at the top to light at the bottom.  I thought this was the way to configure such a gradient

```
  svg.append("linearGradient")
        .attr("id", "area-gradient")
        .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
        .attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", y(0))
        .attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", y(1000))
    .selectAll("stop")
        .data([
            {offset: "0%", color: "navy"},
            {offset: "30%", color: "navy"},
            {offset: "45%", color: "navy"},
            {offset: "55%", color: "navy"},
            {offset: "60%", color: "navy"},
            {offset: "100%", color: "navy"}
        ])
    .enter().append("stop")
        .attr("offset", function(d) { return d.offset; })
        .attr("stop-color", function(d) { return d.color; });
```

and using this style

```
.area {                         
    fill: url(#area-gradient);                  
    stroke-width: 0px;          
}
```

but as you can see from my Fiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/yw46ycse/3/, what I have instead is a solid area.  What else do I need to do to get the area beneath the graph to be a gradient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this the version of the solution your looking for. You can use transparent as the stop-color `{offset: "95%", color: "transparent"}`.

Here is a modified version of your fiddle that i used to make it as you need it.

https://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/OjOWxz

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

a couple of issues to address:

1. You have "navy" for every stop, so the gradient won't show
2. It would be better in this instance to not `.attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")`.  By using the default setting of objectBoundingBox (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/gradientUnits) then you can just use 0,0 0,1 to specify a vertical linear gradient.

For example:

```
svg.append("linearGradient")
        .attr("id", "area-gradient")
        .attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", 1)
    .selectAll("stop")
        .data([
            {offset: "0%", color: "navy"},
            {offset: "100%", color: "red"}
        ])
    .enter().append("stop")
        .attr("offset", function(d) { return d.offset; })
        .attr("stop-color", function(d) { return d.color; })
```

Updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yw46ycse/4/

Comment: THanks for this update.  What I was going for was a gradient that starts at navy and then fades into nothing (transparent).  Would I just replace "red" with "transparent"?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stop-opacity

Comment: I tried to replace "stop-color" with "stop-opactiy" from your Fiddle but that leaves me with an area that is completely black without any gradient.  If I were a CSS guy, I'd probably know better what to do with it.

Comment: probably worth another SO question, or changing this.  I imagine you need both colour and opacity for each stop

Comment: Could you not could specify color opacity with "rgba(0,0,128,0)"? Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rgw12x8d/1/) ? (`rgb(0,0,128)` is navy). You could then temper the tapering how you wanted like [so here](https://jsfiddle.net/rgw12x8d/2/).

Comment: Hey @Andrew, how did you get the gradient to show up in your examples?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but I just set the stop color specifying the alpha channel which will modify your transparency (rgba vs rgb).

Comment: No you understood perfectly.  Your examples are exactly what I was looking for.